# EF Code First Fluent API - lowercase first letters of all columns

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm hoping to set up an EF Code First convention where all of the column names of the properties have a lowercase first letter.

However, I have other fluent API code that changes column names from the default.  I can't seem to find a way to get access to the *current* column name of a property in order to lowercase the first letter.  Starting with the PropertyInfo, as in modelBuilder.Properties() is not enough because the column name may have already been set to be different than the member name.

How do I generically tell EF Code First to lowercase the first letter of all column names?

Comment: Your call, but just curious: why do lower case characters matter so much? You could save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: @GertArnold it's those pesky DBAs.  :-)  I pick my battles with them, and chose not to pick this one if I can help it.

Comment: Also, valuable if your running Postgres as your DB, which enforces all-lower-case table and column names

Answer (score 5):

OK, the DBA's are speaking. Let's bow our heads in reverence and see what we can do. I'm afraid that in EF 5 (and lower) there's not much you can do to make it easy. In EF 6 there is this feature of [Custom Code First Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx) which actually make it a piece of cake. I just tried a small sample:

```
// Just some POCO
class Person
{
  public int PersonId { get; set; }
  public string PersonName { get; set; }
}

// A custom convention.
class FirstCharLowerCaseConvention : IStoreModelConvention<EdmProperty>
{
    public void Apply(EdmProperty property, DbModel model)
    {
        property.Name = property.Name.Substring(0, 1).ToLower()
                      + property.Name.Substring(1);
    }
}

class MyContext : DbContext
{
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>();

    // Add the convention to the modelbuilder.
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FirstCharLowerCaseConvention());

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  }
}
```

After running

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
  db.Database.Create();
}
```

my database has a `People` table with `personId` and `personName`.

And some simple CRUD actions work flawlessly:

```
using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    var p = new Person { PersonName = "Another Geek" };
    db.Set<Person>().Add(p);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    var x = db.Set<Person>().ToList();
}
```

So if the DBA's want their conventions, you can demand a new toy :)

Comment: This seems to work, except for the fact that when I try to create an entity and Add it, I get an InvalidOpEx "The entity type Agreement is not part of the model for the current context".  Not really sure what the problem is yet...

Comment: Ah, that's bad news. I've looked into it but haven't got any clue so far. That's the problem with these alpha features, hardly any documentation.

Comment: Yeup.  I've been doing the same thing.