# Is first letter capitalization in entity framework models the proper way?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, syntax

I know that usually variables in c# start with a lowercase first letter, but how would it be proper in an entity framework model? For example should it be "date" or "Date". In my case sql column names result in a name with lowercase first letter. Ofcourse i can change that with [Table("")], but what is the proper way?

```
public class AppointmentEvent
{
    public int appointmentEventId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Employee Employees { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Appointment Appointments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In your example, `date` is ***not*** a "variable". It is a property, and should be `Date` (although this is purely convention and doesn't *change* anything important - except of course the valuable ease of maintenance from following conventions)

Comment: In fact, they are *all* properties, and should all start with a capital letter.

Comment: Well, it's only your idea for your own design. However you type the property names, the main aim is for the program to work. But using a standard naming convention throughout the entire program or system is a good practice. If you want small cases for properties, use small cases as a standard every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two are properties, so they should start with a capital letter, that is called Pascal Case.

Check this link for [Capitalization Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Also, if you want to keep your tables and column names with lowercase first letter, EF 6 introduces a new feature called Custom Conventions, so there's no need to add `Table` attribute to all you classes.

Check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15160212/ef-code-first-fluent-api-lowercase-first-letters-of-all-columns) that explains how to set up a "first letter lowecase convention".