# Custom name mapping using Code First From Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am considering moving from LLBLGen ORM to Entity Framework.  I would like to use a custom naming convention for mapping the DB column names.

My table names are all capitals with underscores between words.  i.e. ACCOUNT_BALANCE

All column names are capitals with underscores between words: i.e. FULL_NAME

My primary keys are all prefixed with PK_ or PFK_:  i.e. PK_ACCOUNT_BALANCE

My foreign keys are all prefixed with FK_:  i.e. FK_ACCOUNT

I have a huge database to set up, so I would like to use the 'Code First from Database' approach with an auto-mapper to turn ACCOUNT_BALANCE into AccountBalance, FULL_NAME to FullName, PK_ACCOUNT_BALANCE to PkAccountBalance, etc.

I don't mind getting my hands dirty and going into the EF source, but I am currently struggling to find any guidance on the best approach.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Solution**

minhcat_vo's solution below got me started.  After that I right-clicked on the solution in VS, clicked 'Entity Framework -> Customise Reverse Engineer Templates' to add custom templates to the project.

Then I create a duplicate of [Program Files]\VisualStudio\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude (in the same folder)

Then in the Context.tt, Entity.tt and Mapping.tt files I replaced the reference to the include with the new one (<#@ include file="EF.Utility.CS-MMS.ttinclude" #><#@)

After that I went through the Context.tt, Mapping.tt and Entity.tt files wrapping references to context, entities and properties with code.ContextName(...), code.EntityName(...) and code.PropertyName(...)

Then in the new EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude file I added those methods and a PascalCase method:

```
public string PascalCase(string name)
{
    return name == null || name.Length == 0
        ? ""
        : name.Length == 1
            ? name.ToUpperInvariant()
            : String.Join("",
                name.Split('_')
                    .Select(part => Char.ToUpperInvariant(part[0]) + part.Substring(1).ToLowerInvariant() )

                );
}

public string ContextName(string name)
{
    return PascalCase( name.Substring(0,name.Length - "Context".Length) ) + "Context";
}

public string EntityName(string name)
{
    return PascalCase(name);
}

public string PropertyName(string name)
{
    return PascalCase(name);
}
```

Then I right-clicked the solution a clicked 'Reverse Engineer Code First' to generate the classes.

I'd be interested to know whether this is the best approach.  It seems pretty solid though.

Comment: Well, you can always do it manually (using data annotations). But perhaps you should consider changing the naming inside the database? I thought the day of underscores and all-uppercase names are finally behind us :D

Comment: Doing it manually for 100s of tables isn't feasible, and it's a live system, so just changing the DB schema isn't an option (and is error prone).

"I thought the day of underscores and all-uppercase names are finally behind us" -- indeed, but it's a legacy system that can't be changed.

Comment: What's version EF do you use ?

Comment: You can use  custom conventions as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15160212/861716).

Comment: The drawback of modifying t4 templates is that you have to do it again when the templates are upgraded. I would go for custom code conventions. Much cleaner.

Comment: Ok, I'll investigate that too.  I'm just coming to EF for the first time; out of interest, how often are the templates upgraded?  And are the changes usually significant (i.e. tweaks or fully on total differences)?

Comment: They *can* change with each new version. The changes between 5 and 6 were not major, but yeah, *any* change would make you scratch your head whether or not to replace your current templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think EF is later than version EF 4.3, it has a feature **DbMigration** to deal with the legacy system for changing db between developers. Maybe it could help you in some way.

If you already have your existing db, you still use code first. You can download **EF Power Tool** extension for Visual Studio. It basically generate your entity model with the relation one entity - one table, and all map files.

Comment: Thanks.  This approach worked for me.  I will put some more detail about the solution into my initial question.