# How to apply pascal case when using Code First from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, t4

Having all my prior Entity Framework experience with 4.1 and a Database First approach, I've just dived into Entity Framework 6.1.2 and Code First from Database.

I have generated my context and entities without a problem but I want to customize the way that EF generates the entities; I want the entities to go from their database name of `TABLE_NAME` to an entity name of `TableName`.

I've followed the instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn753860) and installed the CSharp Code Templates.

I've also found a couple of examples for applying Pascal Case naming (e.g. [here](https://khalidk7.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/entity-framework-ef-t4-template-modification-to-output-pascalcasing-database-objects/)) but can't figure out a way to apply the techniques to the NuGet CodeTemplates to cover all scenarios (e.g. I can apply pascal case to simple properties and even NavigationProperties but I can't do it when MethodChain is used in Context.cs.t4 for relationships in OnModelCreating)

There's a similar sort of question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717922/custom-name-mapping-using-code-first-from-database) but it applies to EF6 Power Tools which doesn't quite match the scenario now that the Code First from Database functionality is consolidated in EF6.

Am I missing something blindingly obvious? I just want to save myself updating hundreds of entity names after using Code First from Database.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor all your entities to PascalCase then map them like this:

`modelBuilder.Entity<TableName>().ToTable("TABLE_NAME");`

Comment: Thanks but generating all the classes, properties and relationships incorrectly and then having to refactor them is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.